# Install HTTP version 2 using directadmin with letsencrypt on centos 7 server

Tags: openssl, centos, centos7, http2, directadmin

I want to install and activate **`HTTP.2`** on my `Centos 7` server.

I have `Openssl` with this version:

> **rpm -qa | grep -i openssl :**
>
> ```
>  openssl-devel-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64
>
>  openssl-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64
>
>  openssl-libs-1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.x86_64
> ```

and `apache` with this version :

> **apachectl -V :**
>
> ```
>  Server version: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix)
>
>  Server built:   May 27 2019 01:45:39
>
>  Server's Module Magic Number: ********:84
>
>  Server loaded:  APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
>
>  Compiled using: APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
>
>  Architecture:   64-bit
>
>      Server MPM:     prefork
>        threaded:     no
>        forked:     yes (variable process count)
> ```

installed on my machine which seems to be required to enable `HTTP.2`.

As mentioned in the question title, I have **directadmin** control panel with **letsencrypt** installed on that.

I read in documentation about activate `mod_http2` but
as I'm newly heard about this version of http, I don't know
**What's my next step to enable HTTP.2 on my server?**

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html)? You might get better help over on [sf] as this place is for programming questions - not setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have console root access to your server, you should be able to follow instructions at [Enable http/2 in Directadmin](https://mysql-dba.co.uk/2021/01/16/enable-http-2-in-apache/). There are a few steps involved, so I didn't want to just copy/paste the contents of the web page.